# Using Flurl in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, c#-to-vb.net, flurl

How can I use Flurl in VB.NET for GET and POST? I installed the NuGet package and imported Flurl.

How can I translate this C# code to VB?

```
var responseString = await "http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx"
.PostUrlEncodedAsync(new { thing1 = "hello", thing2 = "world" })
.ReceiveString();
```

Answer (score 2):

First, import the relevant namespace:

```
Imports Flurl.Http
```

..and then this should work:

```
Dim responseString = Await "http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx".
    PostUrlEncodedAsync(New With {.thing1 = "hello", .thing2 = "world"}).
    ReceiveString()
```

### Explanation:

In VB.NET, when declaring an anonymous object, you should use `New With` instead of `new`. Also, the properties must be preceded by a dot `.`.

When breaking statements into multiple lines, the dot can't be at the beginning of the line so we add it at the end of the previous line. If you prefer to start the next line with a dot. You may end the previous line with the line-continuation character `_` like this:

```
Dim responseString = Await "http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx" _
    .PostUrlEncodedAsync(New With {.thing1 = "hello", .thing2 = "world"}) _
    .ReceiveString()
```

For more information, see: [Continuing a statement over multiple lines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/statements#continuing-a-statement-over-multiple-lines)